# Javascript replace with regex not affecting string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a webapp task manager.

The app recognises day/month in a string.

I have a function that will replicate selected tasks for today, but I am trying to make the function update the date in the string.

So, for example, `Do this task! 29/5` would become `Do this task! 1/6`.

The function currently looks like this:

```
var d   = new Date();
var mon = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

$('input.replicateCheck:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    //string of row (nam)
    var nam = $(this).parent().find('input.row-name').val();

    //replace existing date with current date
    nam = nam.replace('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}',day+'/'+mon);

    console.log(nam);
});
```

however it isn't replacing the date in the string.

The issue will be this line:

```
nam = nam.replace('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}',day+'/'+mon);
```

Why isn't this working?

**Edit** Following the answers, as requested, here is a working version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
$('button#go').click(function() {
  var text = $('#testInput').val();

  var d = new Date();
  var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  newText = text.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/, day + '/' + mon);

  alert(newText);
});
```

```css
* {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="testInput" value="The quick brown fox jumps on 26/5" />
<br/>
<button id="go">Go!</button>
```

Comment: can you please explain you task for my learning purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing regex delimiters:

```
nam = nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/, day+'/'+mon);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please explain what a RegEx delimiter is, and why I don't just enclose the RegEx in quotations?

Comment: In Javascript you need to wrap regular expression in `/` on either side to be interpreted as a regex. Another way is to use `RegExp` object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide RegEx delimiter

```
nam = nam.replace(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/,day+'/'+mon); 
                  ^                ^
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what a RegEx delimiter is, and why I don't just enclose the RegEx in quotations?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, Start and End of regular expression `//`

Comment: In javascript you should enclose regex within `/..../` otherwise it would interpret it as a string...